# Excel Formula cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
CORP_HQ-[HQ Corporate]
FDLL_731-[FDLL(FDLL)(731)]
FIL_111-[FIL(111)]
SLR_MEX_HOLD_II-[ SLR Mex Hold II (S863)]
SMART_BV_HOLD_EUR-[Smart BV Holding (260) EURO]
```

I need an Excel formula to get the values in (   ) in a new cell.
please help me to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: So the first row would return nothing, second would return "(FDLL)(731)", third row return "(111)"? Is that what you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear however if you mean the result like in the picture below, also see the codes:

[image]

Cell B1:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1,FIND(")",A1,1)-FIND("(",A1,1)-1),"")
```

Cell C1:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND(")",A1,FIND(")",A1,1)+1)-FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1)-1),"")
```

then copy both formulas to the remaining cells in the column